# Reseting only one file from a old commit

Tags: git

I have done several commits since I started to write the code. Unfortunately I have messed up one of the files (lets say it was "messFile.txt" ). I don,t want to reset entire repository. I am trying to revert state of only one file (from one of the old commit). 
Can I do that?
I would be very grateful for your help guys, examples are very welcome. 
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check out that file from the commit you want to:

```
git checkout COMMIT_HASH -- FILENAME
```

Substitute for `COMMIT_HASH` and `FILENAME` as necessary.  After you've checked the file out, you can add & commit it to get the old content back onto top-of-tree.

Comment: Did the job. Thanks again for your help